# Mac OS is reporting bad free space

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, mac, hard-drive

I have a MacBook Pro since 2014 and I haven't had any problem in these months. But today I realized that the free space info that gives Mac is wrong. I add two captures, one from the hard disk info, and the second from the 'About this Mac' window.

[image: first capture]

[image: second capture]

As you can see, I have set my Mac to Spanish language; hope you have no problem to understand it ;)
Also, in the second capture, it says there are about 312 GB of apps, when there is no such amount of apps in my laptop. Even more, if you add 312 + the free space Mac says there is (about 350 GB), it results more than 500GB!

Why is happening this? Is there a bad update from Mac that is causing this?

Thank you for your replies!

Comment: That is indeed strange. What version of OS X are you running? Have you tried booting from the recovery partition and checking the hard drive?

Comment: There is a app that is wrongly reporting. Look at them one by one to find out who is it

Comment: Short answer is, the meter in the About This Mac window is wrong. See [this question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/189083).

Comment: And [this question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/150561)...I feel like there's more but I can't find them at the moment.

Comment: Try rebuilding the Spotlight index and then restart the computer to see if that solves anything (https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201716).

Comment: Try Onyx ... It is a good one for maintenance repairs. You could also shut it down, fire it back up and hold command + R which will take you to recovery. Then click on disk utility/macintosh HD, repair, then in the bottom right click on verify disk and see if anything comes about in red. If something does then click repair disk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Storage tab of About This Mac is based on Spotlight, so try reindexing the HD:

[HT201716 - Spotlight: How to re-index folders or volumes](https://support.apple.com/HT201716)

Comment: Thank you all for your replies! Just reindexing my HD via the posts you gave me (Spotlight was the key) made my storage tab looks fine ;)